# Pycurl cannot connect to host

Tags: python, curl

I am writing a pycurl script, which worked right on linux, but on mac os x I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "curl.py", line 47, in <module>
    c.perform()
pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")
```

any help?

Thanks

Comment: Uhhh... What is that error again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, "url")
curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 8000)
curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_HTTP)
```

Answer (score 0):

solved using this:

```
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, "url")
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYPORT, 8000)
c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYTYPE, pycurl.PROXYTYPE_HTTP)
```